# When did GNOME/gnome-calendar ask for my Google account credentials?

Tags: gnome, privacy, calendar, google

At some point I added my Google account credentials to `gnome-calendar` but I can't recall when. I don't believe that I manually opened the application and explicitly added this account, as I don't ever use it.

I must have been prompted at some point to add my Google account somewhere. When might this prompt have appeared?

This all originated from my receiving Google Calendar reminders from the `evolution-alarm-notify` ("Reminder" panel icon). It receives this information from the `evolution-data-server` for which I have to manage my credentials through the `gnome-calendar` application. It took an unpleasant amount of time and effort to finally track this down.

I am using Fedora 30 with MATE Desktop and I installed all of my packages manually from a minimal install. This was most likely a dependency package inherited from my trying out GNOME Desktop so this wasn't anything related to a bootable Live desktop image or the graphical installer.

When might GNOME/gnome-calendar have asked for my Google account credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely it was at the time you were setting up your mail client, as they often come together. Take a look there - if applicable.

Comment: I don't have `evolution` or any other mail client installed and I haven't set any up since installing the OS.